# File ended while scanning use of \@writefile

Tags: compiling

My problem is that if I try to recompile a text after correction of some mistake, e.g. missing "}", the I get a message

**Runaway argument?
{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {\relax 3.9}{\ignorespaces 
! File ended while scanning use of \@writefile.
 
                \par 
l.128 \begin{document}**

Then I delete the *.aux file and other auxiliary files and so I can recompile without any problem. Howewer if again I get a mistake, compile the text,get an error message, stop compiling, fix an error in the text and try to recompile, again I will get the same "File ended while scanning use of \@writefile." and again the only one way is to delete the auxiliary files. Any suggestions how to fix the problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you show the text in the caption of figure 3.9? This seems a problem of a fragile command.

Comment: @egreg   Here is the info about Figure3.9, however I had this problem before I made this figure:  \begin{figure}[h]  
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{Off-Spec_Kinematics}
\caption{
Scheme of GI off-specular scattering kinematics. Modified from \cite{Zabel2007handbook}
}
\label{Off-Spec_Kinematics}
\end{figure}

Comment: by the way I don't get a point how to put a linebreale in comment. "End a line with two spaces to add a <br/> linebreak:" what does it means?

Comment: The `\cite` command should not be a cause for the error; however this depends on what packages you load, because usually `\cite` will not be a problem in `\caption`. A [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) is needed.

Comment: It's too bad this was closed, because I think it is clear - and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66015/errors-in-tables-then-runaway-argument-at-begindocument has the answer, I believe.

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
\caption{Scheme of GI off-specular scattering kinematics. 
         Modified from~\protect\cite{Zabel2007handbook}}%%%<---
\label{Off-Spec_Kinematics}
```

and delete all helper files before running LaTeX again.