# Help, cant find 'undefined control sequence' error in tex script

Tags: errors, undefined

Help, cant find 'undefined control sequence' error in tex script. I run my script frequently and thought I just added sentence and it now cant typeset the script, with error 'undefined control sequence'.

I've looked at line 63 mentioned at the bottom of the error but its fine. commented out all lines near there at the error appeared. Does anyone know what the @wri means? Really appreciate any thoughts as a deadline is coming up!

[image: screenshot of error]

Comment: your aux file is corrupt, delete it and re-run latex. Usually thi shappens if you kill the job after an error instead of allowing tex to finish cleanly by typing x or s to the error prompt.

Comment: I deleted the biblatex and bibtex tags which do not appear to be relevant to your question.

Comment: the error message is showing line 63 of `Assignment.aux` not line 63 of your document source. the command is supposed to be `\@writeline{...}` but the line has truncated and just has `\@wri` which is undefined.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: hard to believe this isn't a duplicate (it's a common error) but nearest I can find is https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184462/file-ended-while-scanning-use-of-writefile  which has an answer but was closed as being unclear

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Maybe it's not that common after all, I don't usually use something that requires reading aux file and also don't usually kill the compiler. (although there's  [compiling - Unclean .aux file causes "file ended while scanning use of \@newl@bel" error. Why is it not purged? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131709/) //  [compiling - TexShop will not compile without trashing aux files after every error - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127200/)

Comment: (almost) every latex document uses the aux file.  aborting the job and corrupting the  aux file is _very_ common (I've been supporting latex for 30 years, I have an idea about common errors:-)